Cascading multiple op-amps
I am designing a circuit with 3-stage cascading op-amps, followed by a band-pass filter, for a signal centered at 1 MHz, as shown below.
My signal generator can't generate a signal below 2 mVpp, therefore, I am setting the gain of each stage at 5, and bypassing the band-pass filter at the moment for testing purposes.
I tested each op-amp stage separately, using the jumpers (with the input connected to J4 and band-pass filter not populated at the moment). Each single stage works fine, but when I test two stages, I don't get any signals.
I was wondering if I am doing something wrong in the way I cascaded the circuits.
The op-amp is a single-supply LT6200 with a GBP of 160 MHz.

EDIT: C6, C11, C13 are 4.7 μF.
I will try to summarize what I've tried below

I put a signal on J4 Pin 2, got a signal on J7 Pin 1 with the gain I expected, down to 1 mVpp input.
I did the same for J7 Pin 2 in, J8 Pin 1 out; J8 Pin 2in, J1 out, it's all fine.
I tried to put a sgnal on J7, and measured J1 with J8 jumper installed; this does not work. When I put my input signal way higher, like at 100 mVpp, I get a pulse-like signal, then a square signal out, but lower than that I don't see anything on my oscilloscope.

This is the single stage result at either 1 mVpp or 2 mVpp:

This is the 2-stage result, at a few hundred mVpp:

This is the 2-stage result, at around 200 mVpp and below:

I was trying to implement single-supply biasing as described here.

Could you upload a clear schematic? This one is pixelated. Just for clarity, you put a signal in J4 and get an output on J2? And, independently (jumpers pulled out), you put a signal in J7 and get an output on U1? But when you feed the signal into J2, you don't get a signal on the output of U1 with J7 installed? Is everything I stated correct?

Thank you for your comment, I will try to summarize what I've tried below

I put a signal in J4 Pin 4, got a signal in J7 Pin 1 with the gain I expected, down to 1 mVpp input
I did the same for J7 Pin 2 in, J8 Pin 1 out ; J8 Pin 2in, J1 out, it's all fine
I tried to put a sgnal in J7, and measure J1 with J8 jumper installed, this does not work. When I put my input signal way higher, like at 100 mVpp, I get a pulse like signal, then a square signal out, but lower than that I don't see anything on my oscilloscope


I uploaded a picture again, hope this works better

What's up with those "0 Ohm" capacitors? Are they really replaced with shorts?

State what you are expecting from each stage.  For example, you could do a bandpass filter with gain using only a single op-amp. What are you trying to achieve with 3?

The 0 ohm resistor was replaced with shorts
It's developed for a sensing application with a very small voltage, but I am not able to get such a small signal with my functional generator, so I have reduced the gain for the time being.

Unless I don't fully understand your requirements, This whole circuit could be reduced to 1 (maybe) 2 op amps. This would eliminate the front-end filter network and additional complexity.

Do you have bypass capacitors on the op amp power supply pins?

Tested in simulation with microcap v12 https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110 ... Gains are ok after startup. C6, C11 and C13 =100 nF

Are "shorts" J9, J10 and J11 installed.

@Antonio51 Yes I installed them for testing, the current consumption also looks about right (16 mA each)

@Antonio51 When I designed the circuit, I initially tested on LTSpice, and that seemed to work, but I am not sure what was it that the simulator wasn't able to capture

One possibility is amplifier instability due to inadequate power supply decoupling. I don’t see bypass caps on the power supply input pins (pin 6) of your op amps. Do you have them?

You need to actually populate C6, C11, and C13 with capacitors. By replacing them with 0-Ohm resistors (shorts), you gave each stage a DC gain of 6. This makes the OpAmps saturate as they try to amplify the half-VCC bias voltage on their noninverting input by that factor.

Thank you for your response. But I don't think this is the case, when I tested them separately / individually, the output was as expected.
Although this would make sense...hmm I did populate it at the beginning but removed it later because with the capacitors populated it didn't seem to work individually

@tmuuuu There's no way this circuit can work without those capacitors. Please give it a try and report back. (An OpAmp in saturation might also just "misbehave" rather than cleanly giving no output.)

@tmuuuu They absolutely saturate - You have a DC gain of 6 with a 2,5V bias. Your signal is way past railed. Also,  R4, R12, and R16 don't do anything besides add noise. Delete them.

@JonathanS. This actually makes sense but now I am really confused... I tested with my multimeter when there is no input and there is only DC supply voltage at all the pins at all op-amps, Pin 1, 2, 4 are all around 2.5 V, but if they are saturated I should see Pin 4 and Pin 1 at 5 V (which is my VCC), right?

@tmuuuu pin 4 could never be at 5V.

I added 4.7 uF back to C6, C11, C13, same behaviour.

@tmuuuu OK asuming those connections aren't still shorted, what are the voltages at Pins 1,3, and 4 with no signal?

Pin 1: 2.841, Pin 3: 2.873,  Pin 4: 2.880, Pin 6: 5.459

@tmuuuu Well. That DC operating point is normal. See what all the op-amps are when they are all in circuit. They should be (nearly) the same as what you measured. The only other thing I can think of is that you have an offset on the function generator that is not being decoupled. TBH, Idk why you need 3 stages to do what one can do. If you do have a reason for 3 stages, your cascaded circuit would have made more sense if you configured them as inverting amplifiers (or at least 2 of them).

Thank you for your help @MOSFET I need a 3-stage opamp because I am trying to capture a very weak 1 MHz ultrasound signal (< 1 uVpp), I am using a bulky lab ultrasound amplifier at the moment but need to have a more portable solution.
If you have any other recommendation of what might be suitable that would be most appreciated!
But to test at home I am lowering the gain because I don't have the attenuator here and my functional generator can only go as low as 2 mVpp
My function generator is currently outputing no DC offset (so like -2 mV to 2 mV), so I don't think it's the DC?


because the input signal is so weak if I used a single stage op-amp I was worried that the noise level might be too high, but I just don't seem to be able to get this multi-stage op-amp up and running...


Are 4.7 uF electrochemical (C6, C11, C13) or something the same?

@Antonio51 4.7 µF ±20% 25V Ceramic Capacitor X5R 0805
It is a bit large, but I don't have the smaller ones with me, I will replace with the 100 nF later today
